# Split a column using a delimiter coma and rename based on the same column in postgres

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, csv, lateral-join

I have a table with column config and I want to split the config column and create new columns based on the value on the same column

```
company         config
   A    User:xxx,Key:ABC,Role:admin
   B    User:yyy,Key:CTA,Role:Hr,Location:New York
   C    User:zzz,Location:London,Status:Active
```

Expected Output

```
company  User   Key   Role   Location   Status
A        xxx    ABC   admin
B        yyy    CTA    Hr    New York
C        zzz                 London     Active
```

Comment: Honestly, this sort of cleanup is something best suited for the application language which is using Postgres (e.g. Java, C#, Python, etc.).  Databases weren't really designed with this sort of task in mind.  You should normalize your data first (i.e. get it in the format you actually want here), then import into Postgres.

Comment: If for some reason you can't normalize the data, you should at least think about storing that as a JSON value where you can easily access each key.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really poor data design. But Postgres has powerful string functions. You can do:

```
select t.company,
    max(y.v) filter(where y.k = 'User')     as "user",
    max(y.v) filter(where y.k = 'Key')      as "key",
    max(y.v) filter(where y.k = 'Role')     as "role",
    max(y.v) filter(where y.k = 'Location') as location,
    max(y.v) filter(where y.k = 'Status')   as status
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.config, ',') x(val)
cross join lateral (values (split_part(x.val, ':', 1), split_part(x.val, ':', 2)) y(k, v)
group by t.company
```

This first turns the CSV lists to rows, and then extracts the key/value pairs. The final step is conditional aggregation so assign values to the each column.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably write a function to convert this is a more "parseable" format:

```
create function convert_to_json(p_config text)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
  select jsonb_object_agg(items[1], items[2])
  from (
    select string_to_array(x.item, ':') items
    from unnest(string_to_array(p_config, (','))) x(item)
  ) t
$$
language sql 
immutable;
```

The function does **not** correctly deal with embedded commas in the values e.g. if you had something like `User: "Dent, Arthur"`

Then you can use it like this:

```
select company, 
       json_config ->> 'Key' as "Key",
       json_config ->> 'User' as "User",
       json_config ->> 'Role' as "Role",
       json_config ->> 'Location' as "Location",
       json_config ->> 'Status' as "Status"
from (       
  select company, convert_to_json(config) as json_config
  from the_table
) t
```